# How to insert and fetch data from a MySQL database and send it to Discord

Tags: python, mysql, discord, discord.py

I am a beginner and I want to write a Discord bot with python.
I have been connected to my database and I fetch data from the database but I don't know how I can send data to the discord server channels.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='xp')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT dis_id FROM users ")

for row in cur:
    xp = row
    print(xp)

if message.content.startswith('+xp'):
    mbed = discord.Embed(
       title=" Bot Information ",
       description = str(xp),
       colour=(discord.Colour.green())
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(828248385369669642)
    await channel.send(embed=mbed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question was not clear enough. I am guessing that you are trying to get the amount of XP a user has. If I am wrong correct me and I will update the answer.

I assume your table has a column for `dis_id` and a column for `xp`.
If so here is how to get the XP based on the user id.

First of all, if you are planning on making a command, you need to specify a command prefix. Do this where you define your client.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+') #"+" is the command prefix. Every message starting with "+" will be a command.
```

Now let's make the `xp` command, so that when someone types `+xp` in chat the command will be executed.

```py
@client.command() #All commands start with this line called a decorator.
async def xp(ctx, user_id : int): # The command takes in a "context" argument and a "user_id" argument.
    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE dis_id = {user_id}") # Select all the items for the specified "user_id"

    for row in cur: 
        xp = int(row[0]) # Get the amount of xp the user has
        print(xp)

    mbed = discord.Embed( # Define the embed
       title=" Bot Information ",
       description = str(xp),
       colour=(discord.Colour.green())
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(828248385369669642)
    await channel.send(embed=mbed) #Send the embed to the channel
```

So now when you want to run this command you need to type `+xp user_id` in the discord chat. The bot will send an embed with the amount of XP the user has.

Here is the complete code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import mysql.connector

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', database='xp')
cur = conn.cursor()

@client.command()
async def xp(ctx, user_id : int):
    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE dis_id = {user_id}") 

    for row in cur:
        xp = int(row[0])
        print(xp)

    mbed = discord.Embed(
       title=" Bot Information ",
       description = str(xp),
       colour=(discord.Colour.green())
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(828248385369669642)
    await channel.send(embed=mbed)
```